# При очистке динамического массива происходит "Access violation at address 00000000"

Tags: массивы, delphi, память, классы

Парился весь вечер вчера и сегодня на работе, всё перепробовал.
Инициализация переменной массива происходит в теле класса:

```
type
  TGuitarList = class (TScrollBox)
  private
    GuitListSource: TADOTable;
    GuitSolo: array of TGuitarSolo; //вот этот массив, описание класса в аттаче
    buffRec: Integer;
  public
   procedure LoadList;
   constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; ListSource:TADOTable); overload;
   destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

Очистка массива происходит при таком условии:

```
if GuitSolo <> nil then
      begin
      //FreeAndNil(GuitSolo[i]);
      for i:=Length(GuitSolo)-1 downto 0 do
        begin
        FreeAndNil(GuitSolo[i]);
        end;

      end;
```

а его заполнение:

```
with GuitSolo[i] do
        begin
        Parent:=Self;
        left:=20;
        Top:=Height*i+25;
        bufName:='oGuitSolo'+IntToStr(i);
        Name:=bufName;

         ShowHint:=true;
         Hint:=Name;
        Load;
        end;
```

Ошибка возникает при **FreeAndNil(GuitSolo[i])** когда происходит вторая итерация цикла.
Исходники проекта: http://rghost.ru/45054108

IDE Delphi 7

СУБД MS Access

Для проверки создал пустой проект, инициализировал массив array of TButton, создал в цикле кнопки на форме и благополучно их удалил с помощью FreeAndNil(). Подход использовал такой-же как и в рабочем проекте. Подозреваю что что-то с конструктором или деструктором самописных классов (а может быть и с тем и другим).

---

P.S.: В базе есть товар только для первых трёх производителей, у других может экзепшн вылететь.

Comment: файл по ссылке недоступен.

А если не писать FreeAndNil, а просто free, то работает? Так как не понятно, что там в массиве храниться, то разное может быть.

Comment: К сожалению тоже самое, по сути **FreeAndNil** это тоже что и Free только переменной еще и **nil** присваевается.
Файл обновил, теперь доступен.

Comment: В некоторый случаях FreeAndNil имеет другое поведение, чем Free + Nil

Comment: Я пробовал и GuitSolo[i]:= nil и 

GuitSolo[i].free;
GuitSolo[i]:= nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался! в деструкторе класса:

```
type
  TGuitarSolo = class (TGroupBox)
  private
    GuitImage: TImage;
    GuitDescription: TMemo;
    GuitCost: TLabel;
    fGName   :String;
    fGDescr  :TStringList;
    fGCost   :String;
    fGImageF :String;
  public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; GuitName:string;GuitDescr:TStringList;Cost:String;GuitImageFile:String); overload;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  procedure Load;
end;
```

когда писал закомментировал **inherited Destroy;**

```
destructor TGuitarSolo.Destroy;
begin

//inherited Destroy;
end;
```

раскомментировал и теперь нет ошибки!